# How do I chain execution two indepentent Observables serially without nesting the calls?

Tags: java, rx-java

Using RxJava I have an `Observable<A>` and an `Observable<B>`. I want to start subscription on `B` as soon as the first (and only) element of `A` is emitted. I know I can chain it like this:

```
final Observable<A> obsOfA;
final Observable<B> obsOfB;
obsOfA.subscribe(new Action1<A>() {
        @Override
        public void call(A a) {
            obsOfB.subscribe(...)      
        }
});
```

..But this will cause a nesting syntax which gets ugly as soon as we introduce `Observable<C>`. How can I "unwrap" the syntax to a more fluent one - getting one that is more like the javascript `Promise.then()`-flow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `flatMap`:

```
obsOfA.flatMap(new Func1<A, Observable<B>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<B> call(A a) {
        return obsOfB;
    }
})
.subscribe(/* obsOfB has completed */);
```

Every time `obsOfA` calls `onNext(a)`, `call` will be executed with this value `a`.

Comment: but will the function behind B start executing before A has completed in this case? Let's say that B is a long running process that I just want to execute on certain conditions of A (I guess I'm altering the original quesiton now but if you know the answer I'd appreciate it)

Comment: `obsOfB` will start only when `obsOfA` calls `onNext`. You can see that you have your `A` parameter in the `call` method. This is the value that is emitted by `obsOfA`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`switch`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html), combined with [`map`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) in [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#switchMap%28rx.functions.Func1%29):

```
obsOfA.switchMap(i -> obsOfB)
.subscribe(/* obsOfB has completed */);
```

This does almost the same as [`merge`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) in [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) as long as `obsOfA` only yield 1 value, but when it yield more values, `flatmap` will combine them, while `switch` will only be subscribed to the last instance of `obsOfB`. This might be useful when you need to switch to a different stream.